# prompt not passing values by using ternary JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, console.log, ternary

[im trying to pass values for the second ternary, experimenting ideas but i tried three things no luck so far , just wanna understand how ternary works by passing values. I also want to know other methods using ternary to pass values thank you ..]

```
x = prompt('y/n')
ans = (x=='n')?"ans is n":prompt('y?')(ans=='y')?'y':'n'
```

> error:VM27490:2 Uncaught TypeError: prompt(...) is not a function
>       at :2:43 (anonymous) @ VM27490:2

```
x = prompt('y/n')
ans = (x=='n')?"ans is n":z = prompt('y?')(z=='y')?'y':'n'// tried this one, no luck
```

sorry it seems it doesn't allow me to post pics , i'm using console by the way . thanks alot helpful dev guys :)

im hitting (y) for the prompt answer , tried ans also to replace z but still not working . 
z and ans doesnt pass values

Comment: `boolean ? (if true) trueValue : (if false) falseValue` [MDN ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: sorry for late editing on my post thought my picture uploaded fine but its not pls see the code above ..

Comment: As of your errors. It does not seem to be a problem with your ternary. Not digging in what could be wrong there.

Comment: tried replacing z by ans but still not working , its really weird when trying out things to avoid bugs Lol :)

Comment: `x = prompt('y/n'); ans = (x=='n')?"ans is n":z = prompt('y?')` this works for me in firefox

Comment: x = prompt('y/n'); ans = (x=='n')?"ans is n":z = prompt('y?')
"y"  , yep it will work on chrome as well but i wanna pass the value through the second condition .

Comment: I don't understand please provide [mcve]

Comment: x = prompt('y/n') ans = (x=='n')?"ans is n":prompt('y?')

its not passing the value through the second condition (ans=='y')?'y':'n' , i still really cant understand why . thanks for helping me on this im still learning JS weird stuffs

Comment: Whats the difference between this `x = prompt('y/n'); ans = (x=='n')?"ans is n":z = prompt('y?')` and your last comment?

Comment: x = prompt('y/n'); ans = (x=='n')?"ans is n":z = prompt('y?')

i want to pass the value z = prompt('y?')  through the second condition i've tried  (ans=='y')?'y':'n'       and    (z=='y')?'y':'n'

i want the final result y or n depending what on the value stored by ans or z .

Comment: Ternary doesn't "pass" anything. What do you really want? Neither the question nor the comments here make sense.

Comment: oh got it thanks wOxxOm , ternary cant pass values . i appreciate your answer thanks again .